# How to update total payable amount on checkout page woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I want to apply shipping charges to specific user role not all users. I tried using woocommerce role based shipping plugin but it is creating issue with my theme. So, i decided to do this using woocommerce hooks. The user having role wholesale need not to pay shipping.

Here is my code

```
$excluded_role = "wholesale";
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( empty( $user ) ) return false;

if( in_array( $excluded_role, (array) $user->roles ))
{
    global $woocommerce;
    //echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function()
        {
            jQuery(".woocommerce-Price-amount.amount").html('<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol"><?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();?></span><?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();?>');
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    //return $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();
}
```

Now the issue is that this code is not updating amount when i click on place order button and i didn't found php method to update total payable amount.

Can anyone suggest me how to update total payable amount on checkout page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I added this code in my theme's function.php file.

```
function disable_shipping_calc_on_cart( $show_shipping ) {
$excluded_role = "wholesale";
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( empty( $user ) ) return false;

if( in_array( $excluded_role, (array) $user->roles ))
{
     return false;
}
return $show_shipping;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_ready_to_calc_shipping', 'disable_shipping_calc_on_cart', 99 );
```

And i works.. :)